# Posts 2 Posts: query connected -- orderby problem

Tags: custom-post-types, query, order, plugin-posts-to-posts

Using [Posts 2 Posts plugin](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki) I've created `'piece'`, `'person'` and `'collection'` custom post types: any piece may be connected to person (with roles `'author'`, `'conductor'` etc) and collection.

Now the relevant code looks like this:

```
// get all audio pieces connected to current $person:
$audio_ascond = p2p_type( 'pieces_persons' )->get_connected( $person->ID,
      array( 'connected_meta' => array( 'role' => 'conductor' ),
         'media_tag' => 'audio_tag',
         'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
// get their IDs:
$audio_ascond_IDs = array_map( create_function( '$p', 'return $p->ID;' ),
                                      $audio_ascond->posts );
// get collections for those pieces:
$colls = p2p_type( 'pieces_collections' )->get_connected( $audio_ascond_IDs,
            array( 'orderby' => 'menu_order title', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

So, the problem is that `'orderby'` has no any effect. Everything else works great. `print_r($colls)` looks like ok.

What this could be, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, now I've decided to sort in php:

```
function compare_collections( $c1, $c2 ) { 
  if( $c1->menu_order == $c2->menu_order ) { 
    return ( $c1->post_title < $c2->post_title ) ? -1 : 1;
  } else {
    return ( $c1->menu_order < $c2->menu_order ) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}

// and then in my template:
uasort( $colls->posts, 'compare_collections' ) ;
```

But I would be glad to understand what's wrong :-)

My guess is that `p2p_type( )->get_connected`'s sorting preferences are stronger or like that. Excuse me, I am not a programmer :-)

Comment: Yes, it first orders by the connection field and then by whatever else you set.

Comment: @scribu Thank you. And a lot of thanks for your plugin!-)